# Spark streaming multiple sources, reload dataframe

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark streaming context reading event data from kafka at 10 sec intervals. I would like to complement this event data with the existent data at a postgres table.

I can load the postgres table with something like:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val data = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> url,
  "dbtable" -> query))
```

...

```
val broadcasted = sc.broadcast(data.collect())
```

And later I can cross it like this:

```
val db = sc.parallelize(data.value)
val dataset = stream_data.transform{ rdd => rdd.leftOuterJoin(db)}
```

I would like to keep my current datastream running and still reload this table every other 6 hours. Since apache spark at the moment doesn't support multiple running contexts how can I accomplish this? Is there any workaround? Or will I need to restart the server each time I want to reload the data? This seems such a simple use case... :/

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this too, did you have any success, @user838681 ?

Comment: When you reload the postgres table, do you care about past kafka events, or are you just trying to join in new kafka data from the time at which the the latest reload from postgres happened?

Comment: @HamelKothari
No need to update or reprocess past Kafka events. When I updated the SQL table I just want to use it on any future event from Kafka.

Comment: @ClemensValiente Creating a simple object which wraps the rdd and updates it periodically wouldn't be enough?

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, reloading another data source during the transformations on DStreams is not recommended by design.

Compared to traditional `stateful` streaming processing models, D-Streams is designed to structure a streaming computation as a series of `stateless`, `deterministic` batch computations on small time intervals.

The transformations on DStreams are deterministic and this design enable the quick recover from faults by recomputing. The refreshing will bring side-effect to recovering/recomputing.

One workaround is to postpone the query to output operations for example: `foreachRDD(func)`.